# Installing IB plugin

Tags: xcode, plugins, interface-builder

I have created IB kit plugin now i want to use that plugin in other Xcode project

how to do that? I have tried developers guide but not able to get that done ..please answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume that you want your plug-in to be embedded within your application's bundle. If not, you can place the IBPlug-in framework in a standard location like `/Library/Frameworks`.

### Creating the Plug-in

Once you have an IBPlugin project created in XCode using Apple's template, you need a little tweak:

- Change the name of your framework target so it differs from the Plug-in's. For instance, you could call it MyIBPluginFramework.
- In the Target Properties > Build : Modify the Installation Directory of MyIBPluginFramework to `@loader_path/../Frameworks`.
- Also set its Dynamic Library Install Name to `@executable_path/../Frameworks/$(CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH)/$(PRODUCT_NAME)`.
- Set the Installation Directory of MyIBPlugin to `@loader_path/../Frameworks/Resources`.

(when built, the plug-in is placed in the Resources directory of the framework).

At this point, it should work both in Interface Builder **and** in IBCocoaSimulator.

### Embedding in an application

Drag the IBPluginFramework.framework folder to the `Linked Frameworks` group of the application's project. Edit your application target: append to Frameworks Search Paths the path `@loader_path/../Frameworks/MyIBPluginFramework/Resources`.

You're now able to link against the framework and the plug-in, but the framework must be copied to the Frameworks directory of your application when building. Add a `Copy Files` phase to your target, and drag the framework into.

I cannot garantee success (I managed to make mine work, but might have forgotten to relate a step here), but you're given the big lines.

Comment: Lets say I created a Plug In and I want to include another Dynamic Library in it. Where should I put the files and how I edit the Plug In search path? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that usually you put plugins in to the application specific folder found in the Library folder either at the root or user level, e.g.

/Library/Interface Builder 3.0/

On my system I have another folder under that called "Library", and under that called "User Objects" which is empty.

So I would try putting it in each of these folders in turn, restarting XCode and Interface Builder each time (just to be sure)

- /Library/Interface Builder 3.0/
- /Library/Interface Builder 3.0/Library
- /Library/Interface Builder 3.0/Library/User Objects

Hope that helps.