# dylib @executable_path path issue in a plug-in bundle

Tags: xcode, plugins, dylib, install-name-tool

I am developing a **plug-in bundle**, say `MyPlugIn.bundle` **for an application**, say `BigApp.app`. **This bundle requires a dylib**, say `MyPlugIn.bundle/Contents/Resources/library.dylib`. I have relocated paths for library.dylib, as I would have done for a simple application bundle:

```
$ otool -L MyPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MyPlugIn
MyPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MyPlugIn:
 @executable_path/../Resources/library.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
 [...]

$ otool -L MyPlugIn.bundle/Contents/Resources/library.dylib
MyPlugIn.bundle/Contents/Resources/library.dylib:
 @executable_path/../Resources/library.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
 [...]
```

But BigApp.app fails to load this bundle, and Mac OS X's Console.app logs what follows:

```
19/01/10 15:42:59 BigApp[51516] Error loading /Library/Application Support/BigApp/Plug-Ins/MyPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MyPlugIn:  dlopen(/Library/Application Support/BigApp/Plug-Ins/MyPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MyPlugIn, 262): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Resources/library.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/BigApp/Plug-Ins/MyPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/MyPlugIn
  Reason: image not found
```

**It seems that @executable_path** is not replaced by the MyPlugIn.bundle executable path but by the **BigApp.app executable path**.

Any **workaround** to that, without absolute path and so that it will work on **Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger)**? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the web and other SO questions: use `@loader_path/..` instead of `@executable_path/..`. See:

- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html
- http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/08/11/embedding-frameworks-in-loadable-bundles/
- [How to distribute a Mac OS X with dependent libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482682/how-to-distribute-a-mac-os-x-with-dependent-libraries)
- [Installing IB plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560542/installing-ib-plugin)

Comment: Let's say I have Compiled Plug In and I want to copy into it some dynamic libraries it depends on. How can I make it search for them? Thank You.

Comment: can you fix some links? they are broken