# Bundle framework with plug-in in XCode

Tags: xcode, frameworks

there is a post here on how to bundle a framework within an application. But in my case this is not application but a plug-in i want to put the framework within.. The "Installation directory" cannot start with @executable_path. so i have no clue on how to define the plug-in path

any help would be great, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
@loader_path/../Frameworks
```

[dylib @executable_path path issue in a plug-in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094411/dylib-executable-path-path-issue-in-a-plug-in-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this will depend on the application you're writing the plug-in for, and how it implements plug-ins.

You might be able to get away with using relative paths (ie. '../Frameworks') but I suspect only experimentation will show whether or not that works. ;)