# OS X dlopen can't find framework - Image Not Found

Tags: macos, dlopen, google-breakpad

I'm trying to add Google Breakpad (some external framework) support to my application. I have done all the required steps, but when I try to load my application using dlopen, I get this error:

```
(char *) error = 0x0000000100200175 "dlopen(/Users/user/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp, 1): 
Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Breakpad.framework/Versions/A/Breakpad\n  
Referenced from: /Users/user/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp\n  
Reason: image not found"
```

I checked and the Breakpad file does indeed exist in the relative path (to the MyApp file).

Here's the otool -L on the MyApp file (notice the @executable_path):

```
Users-Mac:MacOS user$ otool -L MyApp 
MyApp:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/Breakpad.framework/Versions/A/Breakpad (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 152.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 15.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudioKit.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudioKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Versions/A/CoreMIDI (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 49.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecording.framework/Versions/A/DiscRecording (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.6.3)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 533.21.1)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 550.43.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1038.36.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 38.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 227.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 44.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 751.62.0)
```

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: How have you built MyApp and included the framework? and why and how used dlopen?

Comment: I included the framework. It is added to the Frameworks folder and to a Copy Files stage that copies it into Frameworks. Also, I can find it in /Contents/Frameworks/Breakpad.framework

Comment: I am using dlopen because my application has a wrapper that loads it.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this steps, It may work:**

1. go to **Target** then press **Build Phase**
2. left top of this page you will find **+** symbol, press this symbol.
3. press **New Copy Files Build Phase**
4. expand **copy file** then  Drag you framework and drop in this section.
5. Change the **Destination** to **frameworks**

Hope it will Work

Comment: I already stated that I added a Copy Files phase to copy the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out it was a problem when using dynamic libraries and compiling for OS X 10.6.
The @executable_path doesn't get updated after the dynamic load and thus the LOADED binary is looking for its dependencies relative to the LOADING binary.

I ended up recompiling my framework, Breakpad, and using @loader_path instead of @executable_path, and now everything works just fine.

More info here: 
[dylib @executable_path path issue in a plug-in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094411/dylib-executable-path-path-issue-in-a-plug-in-bundle)